# Uniqueness of prime factorization of ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domain) (and some other resources), if every ideal in a ring (or domain) $R$ can be decomposed into a product of prime ideals, then the factorization is unique up to the order of factors.

*Is there a direct proof of that?* (i.e. Do not prove $R$ is Dedekind first.)

From the proposition

> If $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime and $\mathfrak{p}\supseteq\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}$, then $\mathfrak{p}\supseteq\mathfrak{a}$ or $\mathfrak{p}\supseteq\mathfrak{b}$.

we know that $\mathfrak{p}$ in one factorization contains some prime factor $\mathfrak{q}$ in another factorization. This does not show that $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{q}$ since we have not proved the Krull dimension is $1$.

If this is the case, we still need to show that the correspondent exponents are equal.

(We always assume that rings are commutative and have identity element $1\ne 0$.)